# Type safe index values for std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have classes that collect index values from different constant **STL** vectors. Problem is, even if these vectors are different in content and they have different purposes, their indexes are of type `std::size_t`, so one might erroneusly use the index stored for one vector to access the elements of another vector. Can the code be changed in order to have a compile time error when a index is not used with the correct vector?

A code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Named
{
    std::string name;
};

struct Cat : Named { };
struct Dog : Named { };

struct Range
{
    std::size_t start;
    std::size_t end;
};

struct AnimalHouse
{
    std::vector< Cat > cats;
    std::vector< Dog > dogs;
};

int main( )
{
    AnimalHouse house;
    Range cat_with_name_starting_with_a;
    Range dogs_with_name_starting_with_b;

    // ...some initialization code here...

    for( auto i = cat_with_name_starting_with_a.start;
         i < cat_with_name_starting_with_a.end;
         ++i )
    {
        std::cout << house.cats[ i ].name << std::endl;
    }

    for( auto i = dogs_with_name_starting_with_b.start;
         i < dogs_with_name_starting_with_b.end;
         ++i )
    {
        // bad copy paste but no compilation error
        std::cout << house.cats[ i ].name << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: please do not focus too much on the example itself, I know it is dumb, it is just to get the idea.

Comment: Just use iterator instead of index

Comment: @Slava: That does not guarantee fixing the problem. Mixing iterators doesn't _need_ to result in compilation failure. However, it's better than numeric indexes. Ultimately, there will always be a way to get this wrong. The proper solution is (a) not getting it wrong, and (b) _testing_ to detect when you did.

Comment: @Slava if vectors are moved or copied in memory, even if they have not changed number of elements or elements order, the iterators are not correct anymore

Comment: That's true, then you can write a thin wrapper over `std::vector` that accepts custom index (which is thin wrapper over `size_t`)

Comment: You could also store a reference to the container in `Range` and access the container through that.

Comment: @super this is an interesting approach

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt following up on my comment.
There are of course a lot of room to change the details of how this would work depending on the use-case, this way seemed reasonable to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Range {
    Range(T& vec, std::size_t start, std::size_t end) :
        m_vector(vec),
        m_start(start),
        m_end(end),
        m_size(end-start+1) {}

    auto begin() {
        auto it = m_vector.begin();
        std::advance(it, m_start);
        return it;
    }
    auto end() {
        auto it = m_vector.begin();
        std::advance(it, m_end + 1);
        return it;
    }

    std::size_t size() {
        return m_size;
    }

    void update(std::size_t start, std::size_t end) {
        m_start = start;
        m_end = end;
        m_size = end - start + 1;
    }

    Range copy(T& other_vec) {
        return Range(other_vec, m_start, m_end);
    }

    typename T::reference operator[](std::size_t index) {
        return m_vector[m_start + index];
    }

    private:
    T& m_vector;
    std::size_t m_start, m_end, m_size;
};

// This can be used if c++17 is not supported, to avoid
// having to specify template parameters
template <typename T>
Range<T> make_range(T& t, std::size_t start, std::size_t end) {
    return Range<T>(t, start, end);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<double> v2 {0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5};

    Range more_then_2(v1, 1, 4); // Only works in c++17 or later
    auto more_then_1 = make_range(v2, 2, 4);

    for (auto v : more_then_2)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto v : more_then_1)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    more_then_2.update(2,4);

    for (auto v : more_then_2)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto v3 = v1;
    auto more_then_2_copy = more_then_2.copy(v3);

    for (unsigned i=0; i < more_then_2_copy.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << more_then_2_copy[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of std::advance. It make me think about using also std::begin and std::end, so this might be even more generic.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 Good idea. Then apart from the `operator[]` it would work for all STL containers (almost) and c-style arrays. The operator could be SFINAEd out or you could make a "fake" one for containers without random access.